# EC2 instance changed public IP address. Can I get the old IP address back again?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

My Amazon EC2 instance was running for the past 3 months.

For some reason, the instance was stopped and started. This caused the instance to change its Public IP address. Can I get the same IP address back again for the instance?

Comment: In general, it is not a good idea to hard-code an IP address into any system. Instead, it is better to associate an IP address with a DNS Name. Then, if an IP address needs to change, it can be updated in the DNS record. This will make it easier to migrate / replace systems without requiring any coding/configuration changes in systems that connect to it.

Answer (score 5):

You can't get your previous IP back. By default IP provided by AWS is temporary and changes after each restart of an instance.

To overcome this issue, you should get [Elastic IP](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/elastic-ip-addresses-eip.html) for your instance. It is static IP address which will persist between instance stops and starts. Elastic IP is free for as long as it is attached to a running instance:

> To ensure efficient use of Elastic IP addresses, we impose a small hourly charge if an Elastic IP address is not associated with a running instance, or if it is associated with a stopped instance or an unattached network interface.